# XAMPP, Apache - Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

yesterday I worked full time on my XAMPP server. This morning, I opened it as usual as an administrator and MySQL didn't want to start. This is the message on the panel:

```
14:03:43  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
14:03:43  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
14:03:45  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
14:03:45  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
14:03:45  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
14:03:45  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:03:45  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:03:45  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:03:45  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
14:03:45  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

so I started searching inside the mysql_error.log and I found this:

```
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47064; transaction id 9
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201002 14:03:43
2020-10-02 14:03:43 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I tried everything but nothing worked. Also deleting the file ibdata1 is not working. Can someone help please?

Comment: your log doesn´t show any problems, you have manually shutdown the already running mysql process.

Comment: Yeah I searched for others processes running but I didn't find other than the one in the first place. I resolved doing a complete backup and a redo the installation, and just using the old ibdata and ib_logfile.